# Lumen/Laravel 5.2 Service Container not resolving

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen-5.2

Running Lumen 5.2.6

When I fire up a Job, if I do this:

`public function handle(Application $app)
    {
     dd($app);
     ...`

the dump of the `$app` is very different than the `$app` that I would get if I dump at the `AppServiceProvider.php` level. It doesn't contain the same amount of binding which I need such as connectors and a few other binds that I have invoked via packages

I have put a `var_dump($this->app);` in the AppServiceProvider.php within the register() function and then a `dd($app);` as shown above when I invoked a `php artisan queue:work command`. The dump are different and I need several missing bindings in order to "complete" the job (sending to Iron.io queue, requiring some push to ElasticSearch, etc...)

Is this a lumen bug or am I not understanding something in Laravel?

Comment: How about using app() helper or Container::getInstance() instead of dependency resolution? So far it looks like CLI and web $app should be exactly the same - there is only one bootstrap in Lumen. My only suspicion is the resolution

Comment: @DenisMysenko I have tried the app() helper also, it gives me the exact same one as the DI object and not the one during the boot up. Which is very very weird.